# SonarQube implies a var is null or can be null

Tags: java, hashmap, sonarqube

In this example below, SonarQube complains that `bookmark` can be null or is null, need some help to understand what can be done to fix it. because the `bookmark` is initialised as a variable within the for loop and apparently will not be null

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> bookmark : bookmarks) {
            String bookmarkTitle = getBookmarkTitle(bookmark);
            String bookmarkPage = getBookmarkPage(bookmark);
```

...

[image]
The code shown above is a part of a function that is receiving `bookmarks` as argument.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us how you declare `bookmarks`?

Comment: just updated the questions, bookmarks is an argument to that function

Comment: where is the code for marker 2? may be you are checking whether bookmark is null or not in getBookmarkTitle method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `array/List` i.e. `bookmarks` may return `null` i.e. `bookmarks` is nullable. That's why it's showing like this.

Make sure that `bookmarks` is never `null`. This will fix the issue.

Comment: bookmarks is being passed to the above function as function argument, so if I put a check bookmarks !=null at the very start of this function, do you think that would fix it

Comment: No, it seems to think that `bookmarks` may *contain* a null bookmark. So check that *each* bookmark is not null (i.e. inside the loop).

Comment: yep, makes sense, I have done that, will run the analysis again and see if that has made any difference. Thanks for help